# How to connect web services to each others and connect to different other resources in vnet azure

Tags: azure, vnet

I have a vnet where it contains containers which represent the back end part for a machine learning training and I have two web apps where one is the front end and the other one is for managing the databases which i need to connect it to the vnet to make the calls for the ML part and also be able to connect to postgreSQL database in azure. But the front end app service should be only reached for the final user. So I tried to integrate the database app service to the vnet with service endpoint and doing the same for the postgreSQL but I didn't get anything because I dont know how to connect all these parts to each others.
Can you please help me with this complex topic.

Comment: Using regional VNet Integration in your case should enable the communication between the WebApp and Service endpoint secure services like Postgres.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#service-endpoints

Comment: @SubhashVasarapu-MSFT and for the webapp which I dont want to integrate in the vnet, how i can connect it to the webapp integrated?